# Crossdomain AJAX Call Internet explorer HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain, xdomainrequest

I've figured out that to be able to send data cross-domain in Internet Explorer I should use the `XDomainRequest`.

By doing so I stumbled upon the next issue. I'm sending data from HTTP to HTTPS which gives the error `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.`. I tried adding `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` to the designated PHP file with no result.

Is there any way around this problem wherein I can send data from my HTTP domain to my HTTPS domain in Internet Explorer 9+?

**The code I'm using right now(Which gives the script5 error):**

```
if ('XDomainRequest' in window && window.XDomainRequest !== null) {
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest(); // Use Microsoft XDR
    xdr.open('get', url);
    xdr.onload = function () {
        var dom  = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
        JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);

        dom.async = false;

        if (JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined') {
            JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);
            console.log(JSON);
        }

        successCallback(JSON); // internal function
    };

    xdr.onerror = function() {
        _result = false;  
    };

    xdr.send();
}
```

I also tried adding `$.support.cors = true;` with no result.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
I've fixed it by using `JSONP`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: thedata,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallbackFunc',
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```